# Get a number from a custom setting and display it on the visualforce page.

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have a custom setting with one profile assigned to it and that's Heathrow portal. It has a field called Largest Number and a value assigned to it. I need to display that number on a visualforce page using apex class. My method doesn't seem to be working. 
On the top of the visualforce page I assigned the page to the custom setting

```
**<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="GenerateNumber"  showHeader="false" title="Contact us">
```

and that seems to be fine but when I try to write a method that just returns the number it's failing and giving me a lot of errors.

```
public class GenerateNumber {

     public String numbersgenerated {get;set;}
     public String userinput {get;set;}

public GenerateNumber(){}



     public PageReference getNumbers() {
        return [SELECT Largest_Number__c FROM Number_Setting__c];
    }
```

Comment: why return type `PageReference `? this should be `list<Number_Setting__c>`

Comment: It only hods one value do i still need to use the list ? and do i need to connect it to a command button on the visualforce page to get it retuned on the page ?

Comment: Yes this should be list because query always return list until you put limit 1.. And in VF page you can use `<apex:repeat` to iterate over this list..

Comment: what would i have to use if i wanted to display it once a button is pressed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try simple approach.
Declare a public variable

```
public Decimal largenum {get;set;}


and in the method assign value

list<Number_Setting__c> cslist = [SELECT Largest_Number__c FROM Number_Setting__c];

if(cslist.size() >0)
largeNum = cslist[0].Largest_Number__c;
```

and use it in the VF page.

Comment: Tushar no problem ..

Comment: do i need to have any return statements to get it returned on the website ?

Comment: @Greg no need any return  statements  just use `largeNum` and when you click on button don't forget to rerender the section where you are displaying `largeNum` .

Comment: it comes up with the following error : Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement, does anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: @Greg change your method return type to void and remove return statement.